# Redshift query takes long time on grouping

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have table like this

[image]

I just want to get all userIds and bookId which have just one bookId. I am using the following query

```
SELECT userId, count(DISTINCT bookid) AS num_books FROM table GROUP BY userId HAVING num_books=1
```

I also need to then join with some other tables. This query is excruciatingly slow. I am sure there is a better way to write this query, I just cant figure out the way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select userid, min(bookid) as bookid
from t
group by userid
having count(distinct bookid) = 1;
```

Or for the having clause:

```
having min(bookid) = max(bookid)
```

I don't think there is significantly faster way to write the query -- although eliminating the `count(distinct)` as above might help.  You could also try:

```
select distinct userid, bookid
from (select t.*, min(bookid) over (partition by userid) as min_bookid,
             max(bookid) over (partition by userid) as max_bookid
      from t
     ) t
where min_bookid = max_bookid;
```

This filters before doing the `select distinct`, which might help performance.  However, there is the cost of the window functions.

Comment: Thanks. But how is it different form the query I am using?

Comment: Also what if I want to return both userid and bookid?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question, so I need to get userid and the bookid with exactly one bookid

Comment: @Yogi . . . It is a simple tweak to either query.  I modified the answer.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

distinct will run slow if table is big.
as you are looking for only one book id you can try this one.
select user_id, min(book_id), max(book_id) from 
group by user_id
having max(book_id) = min(book_id)

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question, so I need to get userid and the bookid with exactly one bookid?